# CloudFront distribution shows access denied

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have the following permission set for my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalReadOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                 "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-here/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/ASDFASDFASDF"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This bucket policy is straight out of the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

I have the CF distribution enabled and the `SourceArn` matches it exactly. However, every access attempt gives access denied.

The only way I have been able to get CF to show the files hosted in the S3 bucket is by setting the bucket to public and adding this policy, but this is a security risk I don't want to keep:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-here/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you using placeholder values for `AWS:SourceArn` and `Resource` or your actual distribution ARN and bucket? The CloudFront console will give you the policy statement to use for that specific distribution and S3 bucket.

Comment: I'm using my actual ones from the distribution. I just put the placeholders in the stack post.

Comment: Got it - what leads you to believe that access denied is due to the OAC policy? If the policy is configured properly, it's possible that if your request is not routed to the exact S3 object, the file is not found and you'll see a 403 response from CloudFront. This happens for example when requesting `example.com/about` when the file on S3 resides at `BUCKET_NAME/about/index.html`

Comment: Because I can change the policy to `"Principal": "*"` and remove the CF condition (which you can see in my post near the bottom) and everything loads just fine. The moment I add that CF based policy everything is blocked.

Comment: It's difficult to debug without seeing your config. Assuming you have OAC enabled and attached to this origin?

Comment: Boom...that was the issue! I popped into my distribution settings and turned on OAC, switched my bucket back to private, then pasted the exact S3 permissions settings that AWS provided and I am off to the races! Thanks for your help. If you want to consolidate this into an answer, I will mark it as correct.